# Dynamodb FilterExpression returns only one Item

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with a column called "approval", and several test items in it with values for "approval" that include "pending", "approved", and "not approved". I have 3 items with "pending".

I'm using the following Lambda function to retrieve items and I want get just the items that are "pending". So I'm using FilterExpression. This is my complete function:

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var params = {
        TableName: 'mytable',
        FilterExpression: 'contains(approval, :approval_value)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {':approval_value': 'pending'}
    };

    dynamo.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Scan succeeded.");
            context.succeed(data);
        }
    }
};
```

Basically I want to do a, "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE approval LIKE 'pending';" if it were in SQL.

Weirdly, only item is being returned while I'm expecting 3. I'm not using Limit. Why is it only returning one item?

Comment: what is your hash/range keys?

Comment: The primary partition key is "postID". There is no sort key. I'm not sure if that answers your question? I'm relatively new to noSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, embarrassingly, I was reading the execution result wrong. It was returning 3 results correctly, but only the first item appeared "above the fold" (probably another reason not to use the AWS console for this stuff).

Hopefully the code above, which works perfectly well, will help someone else as a simple example of using FilterExpression.